# Mantener información actualizada cada que doy clic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo lo siguiente, quiero que cada que se agregue o se quite un item, la barra avance, y que le quiten los decimales al precio, porque el sale con otros 2 ceros de centavos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hice lo siguiente que funciona un poco a medias.

```
<div class="range-shipping-free">
   <input type="range" id="price-range" disabled="disabled" value="0" min="0" max="500000">
</div>

<span class="vtexsc-totalCart">
    <span class="vtexsc-text">$ 160.830,00</span>
</span>

$("body").click(function(){
    var monto = $('.vtexsc-text').text();
    var price = monto.slice(0,-3);
    $('.vtexsc-text').html(price);
    console.log("hola");
    var montoFormat = price.replace(/[$.]/g,'');
    console.log(montoFormat);
    $('#price-range').val(montoFormat);
    var totalprice = 500000 - montoFormat;
    console.log(totalprice);
    const formatterPeso = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CO', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'COP',
      minimumFractionDigits: 0
    })
    console.log(formatterPeso.format(totalprice))
    var priceFinal = formatterPeso.format(totalprice);
    $('.range-shipping-free').append('<span class="text-price-promo"> Te faltan ' + priceFinal + ' para envío gratis.</span>');
});
```

con un clic sale bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero con otro clic a cualquier parte del body, ya sea que agreguen otro producto o lo quiten, no se le vuelvan a agregar los decimales y la barra se actualice, pero como esta que se ejecute la funcion a cada click, pues pasa lo obvio que vuelve y se aplica todo y pasa lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces no sabria como actualizar la info y matener el precio sin decimales sin que pase eso.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Prueba con esto:

```
 $('.vtexsc-text').html(price.toFixed(2));
```

Con `.toFixed(2)` forzarás a que un número siempre tenga dos decimales.